# Cannot do-release-upgrade from kubuntu 17.10 to bionic beaver

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, release-management

always if I try start `do-release-upgrade` ( equal with sudo or as root )
I got the message:

```
root@mbc-workstation:~# do-release-upgrade
Neue Veröffentlichungen von Ubuntu werden gesucht *(German means: Searching For new releases)*
Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new version found.
```

There should be no problem with the connection to the internet, because I can ping `changelogs.ubuntu.com` successfully:

```
root@mbc-workstation:~#ping changelogs.ubuntu.com 
PING changelogs.ubuntu.com (91.189.95.15) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from rubay.canonical.com (91.189.95.15): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=18.5ms
```

and I also can reach the http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release page with any browser.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Mike

Comment: Is there any other possibility to upgrade without performing a fresh install?

Comment: Did you try using muon or even update-manager [the gnome updater]?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried all these tools without success. :-(

Comment: In the past I've updated by just updating all the `/etc/apt/source.list` lines to be the new release, so if it says "artful" change it to "bionic" (some PPAs won't have an update so you need to check with the non Ubuntu/Canonical ones). Then just run an `apt update` and done `sudo apt dist-upgrade` (or `apt-get` as it was then). But I wouldn't recommend it and can't guarantee it won't break or leave you unbootable, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, a lot this worked for me.  Had only some 3rd party apps to reinstall. Great.